# ICMP - how to fix "no response found" while keeping different data in request - reply

Tags: python-3.x, networking, network-programming, scapy, icmp

The problem: how to fix this warning: [ Expert Info (Warning/Sequence): No response seen to ICMP request]

The story: I'm playing with scapy. I have two tools: A is the sender ( which sends a echo-request ) and B is the recipient ( which sends a echo-reply AFTER it sniffs a echo-request ). The code of A:

```
  ....
  pinger = IP(dst=x.x.x.x)/ICMP(id=0x7ccb, seq=1)/text
  ....
```

The code of B:

```
  .....
  sniff(filter=f"src host x.x.x.x and dst host x.x.x.x and icmp", 
  iface="XX", count=1)
  send(IP(dst=x.x.x.x)/ICMP(type="echo-reply", id=0x7ccb, seq=1)/textback)
  ....
```

The result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtKSD.png)

It appears that if the payloads ( text of A and textback of B ) are the same, this warning does not get displayed. However, for my goal, the text shall be different. So, how do I get rid of this warning while keeping both payloads not the same?

Answer (score 0):

The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo reply message.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).